# Creating Multiple histograms from a data set to display in the same panel

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to create multiple histograms as below image

[image]

and here is the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avLUg1REJRRzFUZU0/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code I have done so far but comes back error:

```
source("load_data.R")
#library(lattice)
load_data <- function() {
  data <- "E:/Intro Data Science/ClassActivity/Lab Session 5&6/dataset.txt"
  data <- read.table(data, header=TRUE, sep=";", colClasses=c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
}
  par(mfrow = c(3,1), mar=c(4, 4, 3,1))

  hist (subset(data, globalActivePower==0)$SubMetering2, col = "red") 
  hist (subset(data, globalActivePower==1)$SubMetering2, col = "red")
  hist (subset(data, globalActivePower==2)$SubMetering2, col = "red")
```

The error message is

```
Error in hist.default(subset(data, globalActivePower == 0)$SubMetering2,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Thanks in advance
Appreciate your help, cheers

[image]

Comment: In the data you posted, the column names are different than in your example `hist` attempts. The code works if you use the actual column names in the posted data. For example, this works: `hist(subset(data, Global_active_power==2)$Sub_metering_2, col = "red") `

Comment: dovetailing on @eipi10's comment, if you make a _minimal reproducible  example_ you often catch this kinda issues.

Comment: Hi guys, I have an error message after changing it,The error message: hist (subset(data, Global_active_power==0)$Sub_Metering_2, col = "red")
Error in hist.default(subset(data, Global_active_power == 0)$Sub_Metering_2,  : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: @eipi10 I finally get the graph to display but it is not showing the same result. Instead this is what I got: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avQmN0MjEtOGh1R0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The "same result" as what? I've added the image of your plots. What about them is different from what you expected?

Comment: @eipi10 I am expecting a result like on this image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avQkM3WFYwYzFKR1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @eipi10  If you click on the first link in my question above, you will see what I would like the code to do